# How to deploy a WebSocket server?

Tags: deployment, websocket

When deploying a web application running on a traditional web server, you usually restart the web server after the code updates. Due to the nature of HTTP, this is not a problem for the users. On the next request they will get the latest updates.

But what about a WebSocket server? If I restart or kill the old process all connected users will get disconnected. So my question is, what kind of strategy have you used to deploy a WebSocket server smoothly?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, every connected user will be disconnected if the server restarts.

I think the less bad solution is to tell to the client to reconnect in the `onClose` method of the client.

Answer (score 1):

If clients are connected directly to sever that does all sockets networking and application logic, then yes - they will be disconnected, due to TCP layer that holds connection.

If you have gateway that clients will be connecting to, and that gateway application is running on another server, but will communicate and forward messages to logical server, then logical server will send them back and gateway will send back to client responses. With such infrastructure, you have to implement stacking of packets on gateway until it will re-establish connection with logical server. Logical server might notify gateway server before restart. That way client will have connection, it will just wont receive any responses.

Or you can implement on client side reconnection.
With HTTP, every time you navigate away, browser actually is creating socket connection to server, transmits all data and closes it (in most cases). And then all website data is local, until you navigate away.

With WebSockets it is continuous connection, and there is no reconnection on requests. Thats why you have to implement simple mechanics when WebSockets getting closing event, you will try to reconnect periodically on client side.

It is more based on your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets is just a transport mechanism.  Libraries like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) exist to build on that transport -- and provide heartbeats, browser fallbacks, graceful reconnects and handle other edge-cases found in real-time applications.

In our WebSocket-enabled application, socket.io is central to ensuring our continuous deployment setup doesn't break users' active socket connections.